# How to change application user group

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

I've an application that needs to be part of a group i.e audio group. As default the application gets the owner group when it is installed.

Say my application owner is app_46 and group app_46. How can I change my application's group to audio or something else runtime?

Is there any permission or something in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: If I understand well this solution needs access to the Android platform code? But would there be a way to make an application part of the audio group (linux group) without accessing this, only by distributing the app on the Market?

Comment: Hi. Yes, you will need to access the Android framework. This is only needed when you add your custom made permissions. When adding new permissions, you need to deliver the new platform as well. I don't know how this is done in Android Market.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I removed the comment and put it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. Maybe someone is interested in it. To add a custom permission you need to add it to frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml . Then to use that permission with an userId you need to link the permission to a group in: frameworks/dase/data/etc/platform.xml. In your application, use the permission you defined above to make use of that group:

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.your_new_permission>" />
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering where is that platform.xml, you can find it here in your smartphone filesystem: /system/permissions/platform.xml